# Adding a custom java library using gradle from gitlab with a provisioned deploy token

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I got this working with my public github account where I was using something like this:

```js
maven {
  url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tvelev92/reactnativeandroidmaven/master/"
}
```

Then I decided I want it to be private and I put it on my company's gitlab and provisioned an access token however, I cannot figure out how to change `build.gradle` to accomplish a successful import of the pom file. Here is what I have however, I am receiving a 401 server response.

```js
maven {
    url "https://gitlabdev../../mobile/mysdk"
    credentials(HttpHeaderCredentials) {
        name = "password"
        value = "..."
    }
    authentication {
        header(HttpHeaderAuthentication)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try:

url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tvelev92/reactnativeandroidmaven/***raw***/master/"